# Why does$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}$ converge while $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sin(x)}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Essentially for me, the question boils to down finding a convergent majorant for $$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\right|$$ in the interval $(0, \pi)$ thereby proving convergence of  $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}. $$ I can't think of a good majorant though.

Comment: $\sqrt u$ is much larger than $u$ when $u$ is small and positive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty much for the same reason as
$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt t}$$
converges and
$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t}$$
diverges. Near zero $1/\sqrt{\sin t}$ is within a constant multiple
of $1/\sqrt t$ and $1/\sin t$ is within a constant multiple
of $1/t$. Since $\sin(\pi-t)=\sin t$, the behaviour of these integrals
near $\pi$ is the same as near $0$.

Comment: That makes sense, but only takes care of the singularities. Wouldn't it be better to have a majorant on the whole interval $(0, \pi)$?

Comment: Well, apart from near the endpoints the functions are lovely and continuous and bounded, so I'd only worry about them near $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Is there a named theorem that says that when two functions have a singularity at $a$  and are asymptotically equal for $lim_{x\to a}$ then their convergence behavior for an improper integral in that limit $a$ is equal?

Comment: @ghthorpe: The theorem is pretty standard and goes by the name of comparison test.

Comment: but doesn't the comparison test require an upper bound for the whole (open) interval of integration?

Comment: @ghthorpe: The trouble is only at points of singularity and there is need only to consider the behavior of functions in neighborhood of that singularity and apply comparison test there itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with $1-\frac{8}{\pi^2}\frac{(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{2}$.

It has the same values in 0, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and in $\pi$ as $\sin(x)$, while it is a polynom.

I acquired it by simply scaling the first 2 non-zero Taylor-components of $\cos(x-\frac{pi}{2})$ and scaling it to the required parameters.

Being a 2nd-grade polynom, it is not yet hopeless to integrate its recipe.